# Execute contract using multi-sig contract account

Tags: mist, wallets, multisignature

I cannot execute my contract using a wallet contract with multi-sig from Mist. After the last signature is confirmed, the transaction stuck in the "Confirmation Needed" section of the Mist window where the last account icon never gets a check mark. All 12 confirmation showed in the progress. But the contract execution is never complete. I use geth 1.5.5 in private network mode and Mist 0.8.9.